# Call Multiple ASP.Net Core MicroService from One location

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, microservices

I'm new to ASP.Net Core micro-services, I want to know if I created multiple asp.net core WebApi's projects like

```
http://localhost:5555/CustomerService

http://localhost:6666/StoreService

http://localhost:7777/EmailService
```

& Instead of calling above all URL's into web application, Can I call only one HTTP URL and route the calls to specific url and return back the result to client?

something like https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/

Not sure how to create api gateway with asp.net core, Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: An api gateway is just ANOTHER api app that has methods like `/customer` or `/store` and all it does is forwards the request onto the microservice. The idea being that it's a central location to shutdown/scale and the microservices themselves can be upgraded or re-routed.

Comment: Service registry is another pattern you could look at

Comment: I'd recommend you to watch how Microsoft did it themselves with docker containers in vs2017: https://launch.visualstudio.com/keynote/ got 0:50:00 into the video (50 min into the video)

Comment: kind of facade pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/ocelot), which is a .NET API Gateway that is added to your project as a nuget package. You then configure how calls into the gateway are routed to downstream services. This is primarily done through JSON configuration files, which map Upstream and Downstream paths.

It supports [aggregrates](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/requestaggregation.html), which is the functionality that you need. An (untested) example of this configuration is:

```
{
    "ReRoutes": [
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/CustomerService",
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Customer",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
                "Get"
            ],
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 5555
                }
            ],
            "Key": "Customer"
        },
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/StoreService",
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Store",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
                "Get"
            ],
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 6666
                }
            ],
            "Key": "Store"
        },
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/EmailService",
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Email",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
                "Get"
            ],
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "localhost",
                    "Port": 7777
                }
            ],
            "Key": "Email"
        }
    ],
    "Aggregates": [
        {
            "ReRouteKeys": [
                "Customer",
                "Store",
                "Email"
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/",
            "Aggregator": "FakeDefinedAggregator"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would expose 4 routes in your application:

1. `/customer` which would call localhost:5555/CustomerService
2. `/store` which would call localhost:6666/StoreService
3. `/email` which would call localhost:7777/EmailService
4. `/` which would call localhost:5555/CustomerService, localhost:6666/StoreService and localhost:7777/EmailService and aggregrate all results together.

`FakeDefinedAggregator` is a customer aggregrator that you can use to generate the final result. Or this property can be ommited from the configuration, which would simply combine all returned values into 1 payload.

Comment: how i can substitute values of services url like HOST,PORT from my azure release pipeline in group variables,  means that the servises name and port will be different in prod environment so i need to replace values, how I can do this?

Comment: The ocelot configuration is just a config source like appsettings.json so you can treat it the same you would with those. e.g. have `ocelot.{environment}.json`, or use variable substitution in ci/cd pipeline.

Comment: this is what exactly i am asking that how i can do variable subsitution for ocelot.json file bex file have same parameter, host , port   host,port

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Variable substitution will be handled slightly differently depending on what ci/cd application you are using (e.g. azure devops will differ from jenkins etc).